# HTML select on "div" type button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to make a selection on Adidas CA's checkout window via a Chrome Extension (vanilla JS), specifically the Province drop-down, but I see that it is not a traditional select button.

[Checkout Page](https://www.adidas.ca/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-CA-Site/en_CA/CODelivery-Start)

[Sample Product to add first](https://www.adidas.ca/en/nite-jogger-shoes/BD7933.html?forceSelSize=BD7933_600)

I notice that the list of provinces under div `class=ffSelectMenuMidBG` will update where the class name changes to the selected province, but I seem to be missing something else.

Any hints or other observations are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I won't go as far as registering an account there to observe what happens so here's what you can do: inspect the DOM nodes in devtools and their event listeners that's shown in a separate panel, set breakpoints in the relevant ones and perform a selection, then see which event gets triggered and how DOM is changed so you can replicate it in your content script for example element.dispatchEvent(new Event('name', {bubbles:true}))

Comment: It seems like it's triggering something in jQuery, but I am not sure what. Basically it changes the class names and I think this is reflected in the DOM somehow.
Also you don't have to register to go to the checkout process :)

Comment: Nevermind - I just saw that there was a HTML dropdown box below the code mentioned above. Thanks